# How can I just specify the return type for a function and do not specify arguments?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

code like that :

```js
const t = {
    k1: null,
    k2: null,
}
const a = {
    k1: () => null,
    k2: (arg1: number) => null,
}
a.k1()
a.k2()
```

Now I want Object "a" will be controlled by keys in Object "t", I want when I write k3, k4 ,which key is not exsist on "t", to "a", there should have an error

So I try this way

```js
const t = {
    k1: null,
    k2: null,
}
const a: Record<keyof typeof t, (...args: any[]) => void> = {
    k1: () => null,
    k2: (arg1: number) => null,
}
a.k1()
a.k2()
```

But when I call a.k2, there is no tips for args, even I do not input an argument there is no error from compiler.

So, I write what in my mind:

```js
const t = {
    k1: null,
    k2: null,
}
const a: Record<keyof typeof t, (...args: Parameters<typeof a[keyof typeof t]>) => null> = {
    k1: () => null,
    k2: (arg1: number) => null,
}
a.k1()
a.k2()
```

However, there is an error from compiler:

> 'args' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBLC8MDeBYAUDTMDWBGAXDGAK4A2pANOljgEyEnlVoC+6oksAhoQEoCmoAE4ATADzZ+ATxAAzOFIAO-OXAowAFADodXIQHMIhAAp6uAW35R+QiGKhKV8rgG1JM+Q+WqoAXQB8AJQw8P5EZKRhiKgYWHiEGsGh4UzUcfSaevoE4eYARjZJYYyU6GxoXFp4ieiV2LQ1aEA)

What I want at last is that:

```js
const t = {
    k1: null,
    k2: null,
}
const a: ????? = {
    k1: () => null,
    k2: (arg1: number) => null,
    k3: ()=>null, // should have an error like, 'k3' does not exist in keyof typeof t
}
a.k1()
a.k2()  // should have an error like, An argument for 'arg1' was not provided.
```

I do not know type "?????" should be replace to what.

What can I do for both "key contorll && arguments tips"? Or how can I just specify the return type for a function and do not specify arguments ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't specify the type of a variable in a type annotation and have the compiler infer the details of that variable from the initialization expression.

What you can do is use a function. A function can both infer from arguments while having those arguments checked against constraints:

```
const t = { k1: null, k2: null }

function asFunctions<T>() {
    return function <U extends Record<keyof T, (...args: any[]) => void>>(o: U) {
        return o
    }
}
const a = asFunctions<typeof t>()({
    k1: () => null,
    k2: (arg1: number) => null,
});
a.k1()
a.k2() // err now
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=13&ssc=18&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBLC8MDeMDWBGAXDMBXANvgDRoBM2ehMAvgLABQDAZrmMFAJbgwCGEAYq3ZdIAHgAqAPgAUASmQMYSmACcAplFwqwMFm07dRAVRhqAHlDVgAJhBgAlNaBXXRqNQE8QTGOJLSAOiCeFQBzCGweMA8AbQBdeXhJGAA3EA5rSRkQbCN5JEVlIvVNbRgQQqU6emrQSFgeGEQ+QX0RCFEoDwAHNW84GVlpAvoijGw5JuTKYkqyCZDQrBxcAFsAIzUVROmCWZrZAG4GHgCMOROz0kmAehvTFRUcEAB3IA)

Comment: But now I am allowed add k3, k4 to "a", they not exsist at "t"

Comment: I thought that was the requirement.. you can just change it to not require the keys from `t` like this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBLC8MDeMDWBGAXDMBXANvgDRoBM2ehMAvgLABQDAZrmMFAJbgwCGEAYq3ZdIAHgAqMAKYAPKFLAATCDABKU0ACdFo1FICeIJjHEkAFADorPTQHMI2HmH0BtALoBKGPAB8MAG4gHIo+PmYg2OJeSAwwcTCaUlC4mmAwIAx09KCQsDzevAJCnOAQZjH08WhYMGZevjgExLHxqOS1NrY1eAC2AEZSmvV+lM2VrQDM2Gad3bj9g8ONhESZHgDcDDwWGHVbO6R1MAD0x9KamjggAO5AA

Comment: It is a requirement, I dont want add k3 k4 to "a" that not exsist at "t"

Comment: You can see it there, I want k3 with an error :)https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBLC8MDeMDWBGAXDMBXANvgDRoBM2ehMAvgLABQDAZrmMFAJbgwCGEAYq3ZdIAHgAqAPgAUASmQMYSmACcAplFwqwMUQFUYagB5Q1YACYQYAJTWgV50ajUBPEExjiS0gHR+eKgDmENg8YC4A2gC68vCSMABuIBzmkjIg2Hqx8SAMdPSgkLA8MIh8gmyc4BCiUC4ADmrucDKy0kiKyhjYcqXxlMSdSqjkMNIBgVg4uAC2AEZqKtnThERDaADM2OgkAPS7OCCGKiqHAO55sgDcDDw+GHK396S9+8enYCAX9EA

Comment: @Ztory sorry for the late reply, generics disable excess property checks. We can add them back in like this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=18&pln=9&pc=15#code/MYewdgzgLgBLC8MDeMDWBGAXDMBXANvgDRoBM2ehMAvgLABQDAZrmMFAJbgwCGEAYq3ZdIAHgAqAPgAUASmQMYSmACcAplFwqwMUQFUYagB5Q1YACYQYAJTWgV50ajUBPEExjiS0gHR+eKgDmENg8YC4A2gC68vCSMABuIBzmkjIg2AYAZDZ2IA6iAKJGwPi45mpOru4weiTObh5SJBEARAByIIYmKjwwALZq-QBGaioQAIStUZKx8SAMdPSgkLB9iHyCbJzgEKJQLgAOajVQMrLSSIrKGNhyMHE4BMTXSqjkMNIBgVhPI2NzJ6EIivNAAZmw6BIAHpoYYVCocCAAO6LWQAbgYPB8GDkWJxpHusPhiLAKIYQA